# regedit - cmd only shows a blinking underline, but just on specific machine

Tags: c#, cmd, registry, regedit

My program loads and saves registry-entries.
You select the file(s), hit APPLY and it writes it to the registry.

Works like a charm, except for one specific machine. OS is the same (Windows 7 64Bit) as on the working ones.

Tested it with 4 Systems, on 3 of them it works,  on 1 it does not.

What happens: You klick APPLY and a cmd-window opens with nothing but a blinking underline - waiting forever.

What could possibly be the issue?
The relevant part of my code is:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > 0) 
{
    ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    // /s Paremeter : copy entry without asking
    startinfo.Arguments = " /s " + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    startinfo.FileName = "regedit.exe";
    Process.Start(startinfo); MessageBox.Show("Success","",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information); 
}
```

Edit/Update:
It indeed has to do something with UAC.
It seems that it´s waiting for a prompt, but does not actually Show one. But the thing is: Why is that? I used /s Paremeter, which should supress the prompt...

Comment: Could it be something with UAC? Perhaps on the non-working machine, the local user is not administrator and UAC is disabled?

Comment: Hello Ic.
The local user has admin-privileges, he is able to open regedit and read/write manually

Comment: Not without passing through the UAC consent dialog. Shelling out to regedit is really the wrong way to solve your problem, surely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:
If you use regedit(.exe) /s PATH/FILE.reg it sometimes produces a Dialog (from UAC).

To prevent this, **use the following: reg.exe IMPORT PATH/FILE.reg** as it does NOT sometimes produce the UAC-Dialog.

Edit/Addition: You do not have to Change anything regarding UAC - with above solution, it´s irrelevant which "Level" your UAC is set to.

Comment: I guess you need to learn about UAC a bit more. Big mistake that you disable UAC. Turn it up full and make sure you understand what it does and how it works.

Comment: Nobody said anything about disabling UAC - it is still activated. It´s also "turned up full", there is NO prompt if you use my solution.
Anyway, thanks for your participation.

Comment: My point refers to your original problem. Ask yourself how you managed to execute regedit without a UAC prompt. No matter what, you really should not shell out to reg or regedit for this. Write to the registry using the API.